# Yii2 Dropdown widget with dynamic items

Tags: yii2, dropdown

I want a dropdown widget in yii2 with dynamic items. How is it possible?
After doing this i face a error that option is required.
What's wrong in my code?

```
$items = [];
foreach ($all_label as $each_label) {               

      $items[$each_label->id_label]['id_label'] = $each_label->id_label;
      $items[$each_label->id_label]['label'] = $each_label->label_name;
}
print_r($items);

O:P-

Array
(
[5] => Array
    (
        [id_label] => 5
        [label] => Label1
    )

[6] => Array
    (
        [id_label] => 6
        [label] => Label2
    )

[9] => Array
    (
        [id_label] => 9
        [label] => Label3
    )

)       

echo Dropdown::widget([
    'items' => [
                $items
            ],                                     
    ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after checking the spec, it seems the problem is that you use "id_label" which is not a valid option for the widget.
You need to leave this out:

```
$items = [];
foreach ($all_label as $each_label) {               
     $items[$each_label->id_label]['label'] = $each_label->label_name;
}
```

If this does not generate the values as you need them, try to adapt to this:

```
$items = [];
foreach ($all_label as $each_label) {               
     $items[$each_label->id_label]['label'] = $each_label->label_name;
     $items[$each_label->id_label]['options']['value'] = $each_label->id_label_;
}
```

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-bootstrap-dropdown.html#$items-detail